# Django second DB returns None

Tags: python, django, multiple-databases

To set up the two databases I followed the documentation which includes:

- Adding the DB information in setting.py DATABASES={}
- Created a matching model of the model from another DB
- Run migrate (Which created a blank table for the model in second DB)

  from client_portal.models import client_names

  ```
      def try_names(request):
          cn = client_portal.objects.using('second_db').filter(client_id='170155').last()
  ```

  print(cn.last_name)

cn is None. It shouldn't because the data exists in the second DB. My assumption is it's querying the data from the default db because I missed a step.

Do I need to 'install' a router even if I will use using() exclusively? If so, where do I save the file?

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['path.to.AuthRouter', 'path.to.PrimaryReplicaRouter']
```

That example was from the documentation. Where does Django expect the router file?

Thank you for help.

Comment: You definitely need a router. You just create a module in your project.

Comment: For example: Put it in the same location as your `settings.py`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, Grimmy. Can you help me figure out where to put the router module so DATABASE_ROUTERS could locate it?

Comment: `DATABASE_ROUTERS = ["yourprojectname.router"]` if you put it where `settings.py` is. It's just a python path to the module.

Comment: Ok, that's working. Still same result. I have some questions though: Do I need the create a copy of the Model in the app of what  I'm trying to access from the second_db? To query from another DB in views: from this_app.models import client_names; def list_names(request): all_names = client_names.objects.all();

Comment: I tried removing the second_db settings in settings.py and I was able to successfully query data from the default_db. It returns None or 0 count if two DBs are listed.

Comment: What is the purpose of the second database in the first place?

Comment: It's located in another server.

Comment: I'll try again: Why do you need it?

Comment: OK, I figured it out after several tests. It's about the tables and models. I was basically accessing defaultApp_modelName table in the second_db which was a blank table. How do I access the second_db's app_modelName?

Comment: I'm trying to access the database from another Django project in another server. Django Project A is for internal use and Django Project B is for client use.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, migrate names the tables as [app]_[model_name] and thus with different app names on different projects, I was initially accessing the table migrate --database=created.

To access the table on another server, match the table names on both database servers by using in models.py:

```
class Meta:
    app_label = [app1_this]
    db_table = [app_another]_[model_name]
```

If someone else has a better solution, please let me know.